# Pipe Chars in HTML Classes

Tags: css, xhtml, w3c

I couldn't find anything in the W3C docs that said pipe chars, <kbd>|</kbd>, aren't allowed, for instance:

```
<div class="class1|class2">
```

Don't worry about what I might be using it for. I was just wondering if it's "legal".

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. You do know that you can apply more than one class to an object by just space-separating the class names, right? If the class definitions contradict each other anywhere then the one named last (i.e. furthest-right) takes precedence.

Comment: like i said, don't worry what i'm using it for. it's not for applying styles, but for performing actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant rules can be found in [w3c syndata tokenization section](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#tokenization), though it's pretty difficult to conclude from there if pipe is valid or not, as per a glance, it seems that anything is valid for a selector, i.e.:

```
selector    : any+;
any         : [ IDENT | NUMBER | PERCENTAGE | DIMENSION | STRING
              | DELIM | URI | HASH | UNICODE-RANGE | INCLUDES
              | DASHMATCH | ':' | FUNCTION S* any* ')' 
              | '(' S* any* ')' | '[' S* any* ']' ] S*;
```

Comment: it looks like it is ok to use (ie, it's not "invalid") but like @marc said, it's not ok for selectors. which is ok for me because i'm not using it as one :)

Answer (score 1):

It's legal HTML, since the datatype of class is CDATA. You will have a problem with CSS selectors, because the pipe is not a valid character for a selector.

Comment: If you have an element with a class of `|foo`, you can select it with `.\|foo {color:red;}` like any other special character.

Answer (score 1):

It is a valid character in a class name. In fact, I see a website using pipe ( | ) just for the sake of class separation. Which I think is a good practice for readability.

[image: Screenshot classes with pipe]