# Vertical line in css class

Tags: css

I have seen sites use `<DIV class="class_1 | class_2"></DIV>`

What does **|** mean in it? Why is it used for?

It is placed there exactly as I wrote it, with a space on each side.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953758/pipe-chars-in-html-classes

Comment: you have 3 classes and you can use the `|` https://jsfiddle.net/qcuha1p9/

Comment: If it only serves to separate classes, then why the sites still use spaces? Still no straight answer...

Comment: because without space it would be only *one* class name not 2 + 1